# Unable to use ViewBag or any other dynamic variable inside linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I simply want to get back the data where the AssignedToLName is equal to the currently signed-in user. I am using windows authentication, and I have a base controller where I am setting the logged in Windows user first name and last name in view bags. I use them all over the place, so I know the view bags are not the issue. But linq won't let me use a view bag in my statement. I tried to put the viewbag in a variable, and then use the variable in the statement but that failed as well.

"An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" is my error.

I've seen some similar questions, but none with current syntax. Is there a workaround to use a viewbag inside a linq statement? Or even just a workaround to use my current logged in Windows user in the linq statement?

```
    //my linq statement
    var Rad = _context.vwAssignedNotCompleted
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssignedToLName == 
    @ViewBag.LastName && x.AssignedToFName == 
    @AssignedToFName);

   //My ViewBags
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

    var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
    ViewBag.LastLogon = user.LastLogon;
    ViewBag.DisplayName = user.DisplayName;
    ViewBag.FirstName = user.GivenName;
    ViewBag.LastName = user.Surname;
    ViewBag.WSIP = user.Description;
```

The expected result is that I get back the database data for the current logged in Windows user

Comment: var Rad = _context.vwAssignedNotCompleted
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AssignedToLName == @ViewBag.LastName && 
                    x.AssignedToFName == @ViewBag.FirstName);

Comment: hi, try to cast your ViewBag value to string.  x.AssignedToLName ==  (string)@ViewBag.LastName

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but I still get the same error. "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple test, and my code works fine in a razor:

```
var name = (string)ViewBag.Name ?? "";
var profile = context.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
```

Comment: Did you have any data in your viewbag? Because now I'm not getting an error from razor, but my variable is null even though the viewbag has the correct value while debugging with a break point.

Comment: Sorry, I was declaring my variable in the wrong scope. Your code is correct, and you're the man !!! I can't thank you enough as I will be implementing this throughout my application. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to help you!